# Long retrieving data from a table with a column of type VARCHAR2 (2000) by ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

Have:

Oracle 10g table where one of  columns of type VARCHAR2(2000) 
The table contains 1000 rows. All cells have a null data.

A simple select query is retrieved ~6 seconds when it is retrieved by  Fill() method of OracleDataAdapter (ODP.NET) .
If the same query is retrieved by Oracle SQL Developer, time of retrieving is just ~1 second .

How performance for ODP.NET can be increased?

Comment: `Oracle SQL Developer` fetches only about 10-20 rows per go (as many as visible in its grid). To compare tiems, try *fecth all* (or export query results)

Comment: The short answer is to use the FetchSize property and make sure you are using bind variables. Here are some links that may help you: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/oow2014-dotnet-best-practices-2331563.pdf and https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:102993237443221:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PROD_SECTION_GRP_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:10162,,24